# How to judge number of buckets for TBucketList

Tags: delphi, hashtable, tbucketlist

I've been using the TBucketList and TObjectBucketList for all my hashing needs, but never experiemented with switching the number of buckets.  I vaguely remember what this means from Data Structures class, but could someone elaborated on the nuances of this particular class in Delphi

```
The following table lists the possible values:

Value   Number of buckets

bl2   2
bl4   4
bl8   8
bl16     16
bl32     32
bl64     64
bl128   128
bl256   256
```

Comment: <snarky>Just ask Morgan Freeman</snarky>

Comment: <very serious>I did, but he didn't know either.</very serious>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TBucketList` and `TObjectBucketList` store pointers. The hash function they use simply masks out the upper bits of the address. How many bits get masked out depends on how many buckets the object has. If you use `bl2`, for example, 31 bits get masked out and only one bit of the address determines the bucket. With `bl256`, an entire byte of the pointer gets used. It's one of the middle two bytes. The trade-off is simply the number of buckets you'll have. A bucket only takes eight bytes, so having 256 of them isn't a huge cost.

Aside from that, `TBucketList` is just an ordinary hash table like you learned about in your data-structure class.

`TIntegerBucketList` uses the same hash function as the others. If you want a more sophisticated hash function, write a descendant of `TCustomBucketList` and override the `BucketFor` method. In your descendant class, you can also assign the protected `BucketCount` property to use something other than the counts provided by `TBucketList`. Note that the class makes no effort to redistribute items due to a change in the bucket count, so don't re-assign `BucketCount` after items have already been added to the list unless you plan to do the redistribution yourself.

Comment: Nice job explaining that, Rob.

Comment: Great answer, this is probably the best answer for anything I've asked on Stack Overflow.